# npm issue in Laravel

Tags: npm, vuejs2, laravel-5.5

I am getting below error while I am running `npm run dev` in my Laravel Project. How can I remove those error?

[image]

Comment: Are you using LTS version of node? Have you removed `node_modules` directory and tried again?

Comment: What are the error before where your image starts?